# Security Group settings in instances launched by Scaling Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I should start by saying that this is only me playing with AWS, which is why there is nothing about configuring VPC and subnets.

I'd like to launch 2 EC2 instances with an Apache server inside through a Scaling Group. I'd also like these instances get registered with an ELB and be only reachable through the ELB (so no direct access to instances). I associated ELB with both VPC's default Security Group and a custom one that allows inbound requests from my IP via part 80. On the other hand, I configured a Launch Configuration (as part of creating the Scaling Group) that associates instances with only VPC's default security group.

Problems

1- ELB can't reach instances and fails health check. If I create another Launch Configuration that associate instances with both default and my custom security groups, ELB can then reach instances. Why? The custom security group has only inbound rules from my IP.

2- Even if I change the instances' network configuration directly and associate the custom Security Group, it makes no difference. I have to recreate the Launch Configuration and Scaling Group with new configuration so that when created, the the new association gets propagated to instances. Is this an expected behaviour? Why wouldn't AWS console then disable the options to edit instance's config if they're launched through Scaling Groups.

Comment: The security group of the instances must allow access to port 80 with a rule listing the security group of the balancer as the source.  Do you have that?

Comment: Well, VPC's default security group has an ingress rule that allows access to all TCP connections through 0 - 65535 port range and the security group itself as the source. Since ELB is associated with that security group too, I assumed it meant that ELB can reach the instances.